# How to export Node.js V8 profiling info to Chrome's Dev Tools performance profile?

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8

According to Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/) profiling info can be generated using `node --prof myapp.js`.

Is there a way to convert from this generated format to Chrome's Dev Tools performance profile? It expects to load a JSON format while the format generated by `node --prof` is not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

No, the output generated by the `--prof` flag is not what DevTools expects, and AFAIK there's no way to convert it.

However, there is also the `--inspect` flag, allowing you to use DevTools with Node, including profiling. I haven't tried it myself, but a quick search turns up e.g.:

- https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27
- https://developer.ibm.com/languages/node-js/tutorials/learn-nodejs-debugging-and-profiling-node-applications/#debugger-2-chrome-devtools

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for export `.cpuprofile`:

- use cli options `--cpu-prof`
- use `inspector` module. See the [example usage](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html#cpu-profiler)